# Unity's new Input Settings how to simulate an analog stick using keys

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I am trying to no avail to simulate the analog stick using keys only in Unity's new settings package.  This is my code so far, which almost works, except the Vector2.zero is causing the initial values to be incorrect because the following conditionals are averaging using the values.

I would like to set `input` to the directions NW, SE etc when the appropriate combination of buttons is pressed. Also, the cardinal directions should be set correctly when only one button is pressed.

There is this, but I haven't been able to make it work:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/HowDoI.html#use-a-positive-and-a-negative-button-to-drive-an-axis

```
            Vector2 input;
            input = Vector2.zero;
            if (_Keyboard.aKey.isPressed) input = (input + Vector2.left).normalized;
            if (_Keyboard.dKey.isPressed) input = (input + Vector2.right).normalized;
            if (_Keyboard.wKey.isPressed) input = (input + Vector2.up).normalized;
            if (_Keyboard.sKey.isPressed) input = (input + Vector2.down).normalized;
```

Comment: Can you explain in more details what you mean with "Vector2.zero is messing with the initial values"? How is it messing with it, what are the current results and what is the expected result?

Comment: I adjusted my question with more details, any help appreciated, community around new input system is small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNiM53UbGfA).

See modified code below:

```
                input = new Vector2();
                if (_Keyboard.aKey.isPressed) input.x -= 1;
                if (_Keyboard.dKey.isPressed) input.x += 1;
                if (_Keyboard.wKey.isPressed) input.y += 1;
                if (_Keyboard.sKey.isPressed) input.y -= 1;
                input.Normalize();
```